# How to format a curl in PHP?

Tags: php, curl, http-get

I know there is an library made by an individual (https://github.com/tgallice/wit-php). However, I can't find how he formatted the curl. I only want to do one request, so using his library would be overkill.

Here is the string that works in terminal, but I'm not sure how to write in PHP: `curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESSCODE' 'htps://api.wit.ai/message?v=20160526&q=mycarisbroken'`

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$ch1 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL,"htps://api.wit.ai/message?v=20160526&q=my%20car%20doesnt%20work");
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
// curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$vars);  //Post Fields
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = [
    'Authorization: Bearer ACCESSCODEOMITTED',
];

curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch1);
curl_close($ch1);

Data::$answer = json_decode($server_output)['entities']['intent'][0]['value'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not sure what "doesn't work" represents, I rewrote the desired terminal command to PHP curl:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.wit.ai/message?v=20160526&q=mycarisbroken' );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESSCODE' ) );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
$server_output = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );
```

Note: The URL in question had incorrect `htps` protocol so I fixed it to `https` in the answer.